# Is there any good logic I can use to stop computer from placing O on a existing X in Tic-Tac-Toe

Tags: c++, function, random, tic-tac-toe

I have created a Tic-Tac-Toe game as my first project while learning C++. I haven't watched any video of creating tic-tac-toe its my own try and I don't know the real logic programmers use to make this game. But from my own I managed to get my game working good and its almost 80% done.

All winning possibilities are working fine but the problem is that we have only 9 chances and during the game **CPU** places an 'O' where the **player** have already placed a 'X' in his previous input. I have stopped the **CPU** from doing this on the current input of the **CPU** but I can't stop **CPU** from placing 'O' on 'X' of the older inputs of the player.

I have used meaningful names of the variables and added comments on my code for easy understanding for you people.
Thanks.

This code is here sorry for the full code but I can't explain without my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

char board[3][7]; 


void display(){
    int rows, columns;
//********************For Player***********************
    int n=9;
    while(n-- > 0)
    {
    int x,y;
    cin>>x;
    x = (x == 1) ? 0 : x;
    x = (x == 2) ? 1 : x;
    x = (x == 3) ? 2 : x;
    cin>>y;
    y = (y == 3) ? 5 : y;
    y = (y == 0) ? 1 : y;
    y = (y == 2) ? 3 : y;


        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( columns = 1 ; columns < 7 ; columns = columns+2 ){

            board[ x ][ y ] = 'X';
        }
    }

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
        {
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns++ )
            {
            cout<< board[rows][columns] ; 
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout<<"\n";


//***********************For CPU****************************

    srand(time(NULL));
    int randX = (rand() % 3) + 1;

    //To check randX and player x should not be same
    while(randX==x){
        randX = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    }

    randX = (randX == 1) ? 0 : randX;
    randX = (randX == 2) ? 1 : randX;
    randX = (randX == 3) ? 2 : randX;


    int randY = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    //To check randY and player y should not be same
    while(randY==y){
        randY = (rand() % 3) + 1;
    }
    randY = (randY == 3) ? 5 : randY;
    randY = (randY == 0) ? 1 : randY;
    randY = (randY == 2) ? 3 : randY;


    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( columns = 1 ; columns < 7 ; columns = columns+2 ){

            board[ randX ][ randY ] = 'O';
        }
    }

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
        {
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns++ )
            {
            cout<< board[rows][columns] ; 
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }

/*Check Winning*/
   // All Column Winning Cases
    if((board[0][1]=='X') && (board[1][1]=='X') && (board[2][1]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[0][3]=='X') && (board[1][3]=='X') && (board[2][3]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[0][5]=='X') && (board[1][5]=='X') && (board[2][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }

   // All Row Winning Cases
    else if((board[0][1]=='X') && (board[0][3]=='X') && (board[0][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[1][1]=='X') && (board[1][3]=='X') && (board[1][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[2][1]=='X') && (board[2][3]=='X') && (board[2][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }

   // All Diagnal Winning Cases
    else if((board[0][1]=='X') && (board[1][3]=='X') && (board[2][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[0][5]=='X') && (board[1][3]=='X') && (board[2][1]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else
        continue;
    }

}/*End of function display()*/

void drawBoard()
{

    int rows, columns;


    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns=columns+2 ){ // to fill every second elemnt of the array .. just increment the counter by 2

            board[ rows ][ columns ] = '|';
        }
    }

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( columns = 1 ; columns < 7 ; columns = columns+2 ){

            board[ rows ][ columns ] = ' ';
        }
    }

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
        {
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns++ )
            {
            cout<< board[rows][columns] ; 
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
    display();


}/* end function drawboard */

int main()
{
    drawBoard();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where is the computer's move logic?

Comment: `board[ randX ][ randY ] = 'O';` You should first check that `board[ randX ][ randY ] != 'X' && board[ randX ][ randY ] != 'O'` first.

Comment: Side note: I would remove the drawing symbols from the board array so it would just be `char board[3][3];` Seems more logical that way to me.

Comment: Don't think of the board as a 3x3. Instead think of it has having 9 available spaces. Each time a player takes a turn there's one less space. That means when you generate your random play positions you should pick a number between 1 and the max available. Then walk through your array count down down to the number picked but skipping over locations already taken.

Comment: *to stop computer from placing O on a existing X in Tic-Tac-Toe* Right from [the Horse's mouth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames): "The only winning move is not to play."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example derived from your code. The important bits to look at are numberPlacesRemaing, and cpuPlays. The first function counts the number of available places left. Then the cpu picks a number between 1 and the number remaining. Using the number to play, it walks through all the available spaces in order and then selects the value to play while skipping spaces that have already been placed. I left my rudimentary debugging statements in but commented out. You can uncomment them and look at the output, which will show in detail exactly how this approach works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

char board[3][7]; 

int numberPlacesRemaining()
{
    //cout<<"numberPlacesRemaining\n";
    int numberPlacesRemaining = 9;
    for ( int rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( int columns = 1 ; columns < 7 ; columns = columns+2 ){
            //cout<<"numberPlacesRemaining: board["<<rows<<"]["<<columns<<"] = "<<board[rows][columns]<<'\n';
            if( board[rows][columns] != ' ' ){
                //cout<<"numberPlacesRemaining: numberPlacesRemaining = "<<numberPlacesRemaining<<'\n';
                numberPlacesRemaining--;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberPlacesRemaining;
}

void cpuPlays(int toPlay)
{
    //cout<<"cpuPlays:\n";
    //cout<<"cpuPlays: toPlay = "<<toPlay<<'\n';
    for ( int rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( int columns = 1 ; columns < 7 ; columns = columns+2 ){
            //cout<<"cpuPlays: board["<<rows<<"]["<<columns<<"] = "<<board[rows][columns]<<'\n';
            if( board[rows][columns] == ' ' ){
                //cout<<"cpuPlays: counts toPlay = "<<toPlay<<'\n';
                --toPlay;
            }
            if(toPlay == 0)
            {
                board[rows][columns] = 'O';
                //cout<<"cpuPlays: make play board["<<rows<<"]["<<columns<<"] = "<<board[rows][columns]<<"\n\n";
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void display(){
    int rows, columns;
//********************For Player***********************
    int n=9;
    while(n-- > 0) {
        int x,y;
        cin>>x;
        x = (x == 1) ? 0 : x;
        x = (x == 2) ? 1 : x;
        x = (x == 3) ? 2 : x;
        cin>>y;
        y = (y == 3) ? 5 : y;
        y = (y == 0) ? 1 : y;
        y = (y == 2) ? 3 : y;

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
            for ( columns = 1 ; columns < 7 ; columns = columns+2 ){
                board[ x ][ y ] = 'X';
            }
        }

        for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
        {
            for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns++ )
            {
                cout<< board[rows][columns] ; 
            }
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout<<"\n";


//***********************For CPU****************************
    srand(time(NULL));
    int remaning = numberPlacesRemaining();
    cout<<"remaing = " << remaning << '\n';
    int randX = (rand() % remaning) + 1;

    //To check randX and player x should not be same
    cpuPlays(randX);

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ )
    {
        for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns++ )
        {
            cout<< board[rows][columns] ; 
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }

/*Check Winning*/
   // All Column Winning Cases
    if((board[0][1]=='X') && (board[1][1]=='X') && (board[2][1]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[0][3]=='X') && (board[1][3]=='X') && (board[2][3]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[0][5]=='X') && (board[1][5]=='X') && (board[2][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }

   // All Row Winning Cases
    else if((board[0][1]=='X') && (board[0][3]=='X') && (board[0][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[1][1]=='X') && (board[1][3]=='X') && (board[1][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[2][1]=='X') && (board[2][3]=='X') && (board[2][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }

   // All Diagnal Winning Cases
    else if((board[0][1]=='X') && (board[1][3]=='X') && (board[2][5]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else if((board[0][5]=='X') && (board[1][3]=='X') && (board[2][1]=='X')){
        cout<<"You won the game"<<endl;
        break;
        }
    else
        continue;
    }

}/*End of function display()*/

void drawBoard()
{
    int rows, columns;

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns=columns+2 ){ // to fill every second elemnt of the array .. just increment the counter by 2
            board[ rows ][ columns ] = '|';
        }
    }

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( columns = 1 ; columns < 7 ; columns = columns+2 ){
            board[ rows ][ columns ] = ' ';
        }
    }

    for ( rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ) {
        for ( columns = 0 ; columns < 7 ; columns++ ) {
            cout<< board[rows][columns] ; 
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    display();


}/* end function drawboard */

int main()
{
    drawBoard();
    return 0;
}
```

SECOND VERSION -- more modular and incorporates all the ideas from the comments associated with the question.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

char board[3][3] = {{' ', ' ', ' '},{' ', ' ', ' '},{' ', ' ', ' '}};

int numberPlacesRemaining()
{
    int numberPlacesRemaining = 9;
    for ( int rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( int columns = 0 ; columns < 3 ; columns++ ){
            if( board[rows][columns] != ' ' ){
                numberPlacesRemaining--;
            }
        }
    }
    return numberPlacesRemaining;
}

void toPlay(int row, int column, char player){
    board[row][column] = player;
}

void toPlay(int play, char player){
    for ( int rows = 0 ; rows < 3 ; rows++ ){
        for ( int columns = 0 ; columns < 3 ; columns++ ){
            if( board[rows][columns] == ' ' ){
                --play;
            }
            if(play == 0)
            {
                board[rows][columns] = player;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

void cpuPlays()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int remaning = numberPlacesRemaining();
    int choice = (rand() % remaning) + 1;
    cout << "cpu plays" << std::endl;
    toPlay(choice,'O');
}

void drawBoard()
{
    for( int row = 0 ; row < 3 ; row++ )
    {
        cout << '|' << board[row][0] << '|' << board[row][1] << '|' << board[row][2] << '|' << '\n';
    }
}

bool hasAlreadyBeenPlayed(int row, int column)
{
    return board[row][column] != ' ';
}

void playerPlays()
{
    cout<<"Your Move\n";

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    do{
        cout<<"Position down? ";
        do{
            cin>>x;
            if( x < 1 || x > 3 )
            {
                cout<<"Plese pick a number between 1 and 3. ";
                x = 0;
            }
        } while(x==0);

        cout<<"Position across? ";
        do {
            cin>>y;
            if( y < 1 || y > 3 )
            {
                cout<<"Plese pick a number between 1 and 3. ";
                y = 0;
            }
        } while(y==0);

        x--;y--;
        if(hasAlreadyBeenPlayed(x,y))
        {
            cout<<"Sorry, but that location has alreayd benn played. Please try agian.\n";
        }
    } while(hasAlreadyBeenPlayed(x,y));
    toPlay(x,y,'X');
}

char whoWonAcross() {
    for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){
        if( board[row][0] != ' '){
            if( board[row][0] == board[row][1] && board[row][0] == board[row][2] ){
                return board[row][0];
            }
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}
char whoWonUpwards() {
    for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++){
        if( board[0][column] != ' '){
            if( board[0][column] == board[1][column] && board[0][column] == board[2][column] ){
                return board[0][column];
            }
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}
char whoWonDiagonal() {
    if( board[1][1] != ' '){
        if( board[1][1] == board[0][0] && board[1][1] == board[2][2] ){
            return board[1][1]; 
        }
        if ( board[1][1] == board[0][2] && board[1][1] == board[2][0] ){
            return board[1][1]; 
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}


char whoWon()
{
    char result = whoWonAcross();
    if( result != ' ' ) return result;

    result = whoWonUpwards();
    if( result != ' ' ) return result;

    result = whoWonDiagonal();
    if( result != ' ' ) return result;

    return ' ';
}

bool gameOver()
{
    char who = whoWon();
    if( who == ' ') {
        if( numberPlacesRemaining() == 0 ){
            cout << "Draw game!";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    cout << "Congratulations to " << who << " for such an excelent game." << std::endl;
    return true;
}

void display(){
    for(drawBoard();;){
        playerPlays();
        drawBoard();
        if(gameOver() ){
            break;
        }
        cpuPlays();
        drawBoard();
        if(gameOver() ){
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    display();
    return 0;
}
```